# Type theoretic counterpart of calculus of constructions?

Tags: reference-request, online-resources, type-theory, intuitionistic-logic

The Curry-Howard correspondence connects the simply typed calculus with proofs in propositional intuitionistic logic. This correspondence can be extended between System F (polymorphic typed calculus) and proofs in first-order logic.

I've been wondering what would be the logical/type-theoretical counterpart of a dependent system like the [calculus of constructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_constructions). The wiki article says

> The Calculus of Constructions can be considered an extension of the Curry–Howard isomorphism. [...] The Calculus of Constructions extends this isomorphism to proofs in the full intuitionistic predicate calculus, [...]

I'm not sure what "the full intuitionistic predicate calculus" means (no internal link or citation provided there, plus I'm looking for a type theory, not a calculus) but, judging from what I read in the article about [intuitionistic type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory), my intuition sees a correspondence that smells Curry-Howardy. Is there, though, some (more formal) discussion on this?

Comment: I can find some discussion when googling about the calculus of *inductive* constructors.

Comment: The calculus of constructions *is* a type theory, and is the type theory of the programming language Coq.

Comment: @SiddharthBhat The CoC *is* a type theory as much as System F is. The type-checking rules can be isomorphically associated to the natural deduction rules for predicate logic. This isomorphism allows you to say that a calculus *is* a type theory.

Comment: @SiddharthBhat However, historically the two have been developed and studied separately and at some point researchers came to realize that actually they're talking about the same thing. My question is "What is the analogy for the CoC? What is the *name* of the type theory (studied in the context of type theory) that corresponds to the CoC (which I see as part of the programming languages theory)?"

Comment: Ultimately, I would like to fill in the sentence "The terms in the CoC correspond to proofs in <enter name of natural deduction system>".

Comment: Siddharth Bhat was right saying CoC is the type theory. CoC is a variation on Martin-Löf Type Theory and not "via CH". This wasn't some accident that was discovered later, but [a deliberate design decision taken from Automath](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/credits.html). You can make some connections to intuitionistic higher-order logic, but there isn't some well-known, named logic that CoC tightly corresponds to. Proof-relevant higher order logics and dependent type theories start to blur into each other as the separation between predicates and proofs/types and terms goes away.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "a calculus" (presumably something like a lambda calculus), but "predicate calculus" is just a synonym for predicate logic. Also, System F corresponds to intuitionistic second-order *propositional* logic (SOPL) not to be confused with second-order (predicate) logic (SOL). There is nothing that corresponds to the terms of first-order logic in System F. The type theory that corresponds to intuitionistic first-order logic is usually called $\lambda P$ and is a very basic dependently typed lambda calculus. It is the basis for the LF family (e.g. Elf and Twelf).